# extra networking charges in gougle cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

i'm currently in Google Cloud app engine and would like to switch to GC Functions. I'm using Atlas Mongodb as a database, sendgrid for mailing and Google recaptcha api. I'm wondering if I may be charged for all these engaged networking traffic. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For all billing questions about Cloud Functions, you should familiarize yourself with the [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing).  In particular, it's stated that [outbound networking is billed](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#networking), when performed outside the GCP region where you function has is deployed.